# Why is my CentOS 6 system doing IPv6 lookups?

Tags: centos, ipv6

I have a fairly recently installed CentOS 6.6 system.  I have disabled IPv6 as best I can:

- IPV6INIT=no in ifcfg-[eth0|lo]
- net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 in /etc/sysctl.conf
- net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 in /etcsysctl.conf

However when I do DNS lookups, most notably for yum updates, I keep getting offered IPv6 addresses, which of course are not reachable; I presume from this that my system is asking for AAAA records instead of A records when doing a name lookup.

```
Downloading Packages:
http://centos.mirror.iweb.ca/6.6/os/x86_64/Packages/ConsoleKit-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f748:10:12:0:ce17:705:1: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
```

How do I make my system only ask for IPv4 addresses?

Comment: Yes, I did.  Both, actually, in that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description sounds almost as though you might need to configure `/etc/gai.conf`. But I'll hold on that for blacklisting IPv6. To prevent the IPv6 module from binding to the IPv6 networking stack, add the line below to "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf" (or a different file name):

```
options ipv6 disable=1
```

Then, `reboot`.

This will allow the loading of the IPv6 module in order to satisfy any other modules that depend on it while disabling support for the IPv6 protocol.

EDIT

Also, you missed `NETWORKING_IPV6=no` in `/etc/sysconfig/network`.

Comment: the line in /etc/sysconfig/network is the missing piece.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this issue, You need to add below paramater in */etc/yum.conf*

```
ip_resolve=4
```

Comment: This would work.

However, there is probably something wrong with the system outside just yum and that should be addressed.